# Copy Artifact Plugin - Copy from WORKSPACE without the path from Artifacts to copy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to copy Jenkins `WORKSPACE` items from a job to another using **Copy Artifact Plugin** as follows:

- from Job A's `WORKSPACE`: `/output/bundle/<all files and folders>`
- to Job B under `${AUT}` path which is: `c:/AUT`

**Plugin setup**

- **Project name**: `project-build`
- **Which build**: `Copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build`
- **Artifacts to copy**: `output/bundle/**`
- **Target directory**: `${AUT}`

The copy is performed but the content of the Target Directory will be:
`c:/AUT/output/bundle/<all files and folders>`

How can I modify the **Artifacts to copy** or **Target directory** in order to have the following result:
`c:/AUT/<all files and folders>`?

Just to be more clear, I would like to copy only the content of `/output/bundle/<all files and folders>` not having the `/output/bundle/` path in the **Target directory**.

Comment: 2 years later it seems there's no solution but to do it using shell/batch commands ._.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a "flatten directory" option in the advanced setting, which will expand whatever you have in the source directory to the target directory. However,  this will also expand the folder in the source directory, to solve that you need to be more specific on the source folder and the destination folder. For example, src: output/bundle/a/**, dst: ${AUT}/a/

Comment: Sorry, @lomo44, I don't get it. I cannot modify the source directory (Artifacts to copy) since belongs to an another job. The "Flatten directories" doesn't work because I need the original folder structure and checking this option, as you mentioned, the Target directory won't contain folders. What's the purpose of that /a/? It's an additional folder in the path? Could you please explain what "you need to be more specific" means? Thanks!